# Find the closest number in an array in O(1) time using preprocessing

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

### Problem Statement

I have a sorted array of integers `arr = [1, 5, 7, 8, 9]` as well as an integer `target`. The array `arr` will not change.

I want to find the closest value to `target` within `arr`.

Example: Say that `target = 4`. Then, the answer would be `5`. This is because `abs(target - 5)` is less than the distance between `target` and all other numbers.

### One Approach that is Too Slow

Without preprocessing, an efficient way to do this would be to apply Binary Search, such as by using `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` from the C++ standard library. This would find the result in `O(log(n))` time.

But `O(log(n))` is **not good enough** for real-time requirements.

### Question - Can this be Optimized using Preprocessing?

I will be running multiple queries with different values of `target` on the non-changing array `arr`. How can I **preprocess** the data (regardless of time complexity) to find the closest value to `target` in *constant time* (`O(1)`) for any `target`? Or is this even possible?

Note that the numbers in the array may potentially be *very large* (10^9), so we cannot simply compute the result for each `target` variable ahead of time and store it in a dictionary.

Comment: Y-fast-trie is O(log log m) for successor/predecessor, where m is the range. If the range is fixed at 10^9, as you seem to suggest, that's technically O(1).

Comment: How large is the range of possible targets?

Comment: As evidenced by the only given answer so far, this question may be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

How about using numpy?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 5, 7, 8, 9])
target = 4
arr[abs((arr - target)).argmin()]
```

Edit.
target in this code is variable.
Check the following function.

```
import numpy as np
def closet_number(arr, target):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    return arr[abs((arr - target)).argmin()]

closet_number([1,5,7,8,9], 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I should have been more clear that `target` is a variable. I need to find the closest number to `target` in the array for multiple queries in which `target` can be any number.

Comment: Target in the code is variable. Check the function I made in the edited version.

Comment: Unless we pre-compute the `(arr - target).argmin()` for all possible values of `target`, this approach will be O(N) time complexity at runtime (slower than the binary search method). I suppose we could pre-compute solutions for all possible values of `target`, but this of course is not ideal.